# How To Like Facebook Page using App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I want to like facebook Page throught [Facebook Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#triggering) using **facebook SDK 4.2.0** but not work for me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.gift_layout);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    //callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    preference = new SharedPreference(GiftActivity.this);
    getId();
    getHashKey();
    getFacebookLike();
}
```

// Methed declairation

```
private void getFacebookLike() {

    Log.i(TAG, "To Facebook Like ");
    LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.fb_like_page);
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType( PreferenceAttribute.LIKE_URL, LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);

}
```

But when i am using WebView it work fine.so how can we use facebook **LikeView**.

Any body Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Liking a Page with the API is not possible at all. You will have to use the Like Button/Plugin for that.

Comment: i have tried LikeButton but how to redirect fb page after click on likebutton please guide how to implement it......

Comment: you should not redirect. always allow the user to unlike. like gating is not allowed anyway in any form.